# Query Parameters Filter

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm currently trying to build my `whereStatement` based on the query params. For example `app.com/users?filter_one=param&filter_two=param2` I understand this call using a basic where clause by using `req.params`, but I'm trying to also filter based on greater than, less than, between, and OR statements if passed through.

```
db.findAndCountAll({
  where: whereStatement
})
.then(collection => {
  res.status(200).json({status: "success", collection})
})
.catch(err => {
  res.status(400).json({status:"failed", error: err})
});
```

Completely loss on how to dynamically build this `whereStatement`. Also how the url path would look with those kind of filters. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Just need some help being lead in the right direction.

Using Sequelize latest version 4.38

Comment: I'd suggest you to say which version of Sequelize you're working with since some methods may change from one version to another.

Comment: added version im using

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to create queries [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html). The documentation show you how to use `and`, `or`, `less than`, etcetera.

For example

```
whereStatement = {
  someProperty: {
    [Op.or]: {
      [Op.lt]: 1000,
      [Op.eq]: null
    }
  }
};
// someProperty < 1000 OR someProperty IS NULL
```

Comment: I get how to build the where statement using the operators. I meant how to build them to be used only if those params are passed through, I'm guessing this would fail without the [Op.or] criteria. I also don't understand how the url path would look in this case using an `or`. Somethiing like this app.com/users?gt=1 `or` lt=10